# Capture response of form post with input[type="file"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, internet-explorer, http-post

I have the following html code:

```
        <form action="@Url.Action("SavePicture", "Pictures")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="SavePictureForm" target="my_iframe">
            <input type="file" name="file" class="fileUpload" multiple accept="image/*" />
        </form>
        <iframe name="my_iframe" id="my_iframe" src="" class="hhidden"></iframe>
```

The `form` is used to upload images. The problem is that the `web.config` on the server has file content size limitation.

If I upload a file of 10MB yet the server accepts maximum 5MB, I will get an error.

Here's how the error looks like in Chrome:

[image: chrome error on uploading file with size greater than accepted]

I handle the error in `Global.asax.cs` like this

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var exle = Context.Server.GetLastError() as System.Web.HttpException;

    if (exle != null && exle.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.RuntimeErrorPostTooLarge)
    {
        HandlePostTooLargeError();
    }
}

private void HandlePostTooLargeError()
{
    Server.ClearError();
    this.Context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    this.Context.Response.ClearContent();
    this.Context.Response.StatusCode = 503;
    this.Context.Response.Status = "503 Image too large";
    this.Context.Response.StatusDescription = "Image too large";
    this.Context.Response.Flush();
    this.Context.Response.End();
}
```

My problem is that all browsers except Internet Explorer will display a dialog with the message "Image too large".

Internet Explorer handles internally the form post, gets the `503` error code but does nothing. (I can see this in the `Developer Tools`, `Network` tab)

Here's IE's form post response captured by Developer Tools/Network

[image: ie's handling of form post error]

Yet the error is only seen in IE's Developer Tools, the user cannot guess what's wrong.

I need a solution to inform the user that the upload failed for the specific reason, yet I cannot find a solution to the problem.

Is it possible to capture the response of form post and display it to the user?